# How to pause a batch script on a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a below batch script:

```
@echo off

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Project
CALL init_env.bat

cd C:\Users\Documents\Project\Release

START app.exe -ver 133

echo application has been stopped
```

This starts the `app.exe`. On the terminal it also says `application has been stopped`. Is there any way I can pause the script after executing the line `START app.exe -ver 133` and only run `echo application has been stopped` when the app was closed or crashed for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `START` should be removed because it starts the executable `app.exe` as separate process being executed parallel to `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. Then `cmd.exe` processing the batch file starts `app.exe` and waits with further processing of the batch file until `app.exe` terminated itself.

It is also recommended to always enclose a file/folder string in `"` even on not really being necessary. So `cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Project"` and `call "init_env.bat"` should be used or even better `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\init_env.bat"` if that works also because of batch file `init_env.bat` is written to work independent on what is the current directory on execution. And last `cd /D "C:\Users\Documents\Project\Release"` and `"app.exe" -ver 133` should be written in the batch file.

Run in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window `cd /?` for help on command **CD** and meaning of option `/D`.
`start /?` outputs the help for command **START** in cmd window.

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\init_env.bat"
cd /D "C:\Users\Documents\Project\Release"
"app.exe" -ver 133
echo application has been stopped
```

See also the predefined [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).